# file_get_contents same host

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I have problem with using `file_get_contents` when calling url in same domain. Remote php files are working. But when i call a local php file via `file_get_contents('http:://www.same-domain...')` i get an empty string. When i call the php via `file_get_contents('relative_path_to_file')` than php will not be parsed.

Because i'm on a shared hosting i added a php.ini with `allow_url_fopen = On` in all used directories. Without the ini file result of the call is `bool-false`. And with the ini file `an empty string`

I alse tried to solve it with cURL. But the same result!

Does someboy has an idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: Can you try using `include` instead of `file_get_contents` and see if that also returns empty?

Comment: Include is working but i must send a querystring via $_GET. Include does not support this

Comment: is the problem that you are using `http:://` instead of `http://` ?

Comment: Include files should have access to already defined variables.  So if you can define the variable you would otherwise be passing to the include file through $_GET, you should be able to access it in your include file as a regular variable.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? There's basically no reason to query the same server using an HTTP request. There's likely a much better solution for what you're trying to do. You say you get an empty string... what else do you expect and why? Show a complete example.

Comment: The script i want to call is a webservice script, which is called via js. But in this case i had to call it via php. On my servers its working fine. Not i have included the file and simulated the query-string. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including your file instead of trying to access it over HTTP.  Include files have access to previously defined variables.  So you don't need to set a variable and pass it to the file using $_GET.  You can just access it directly from the included file.

test1.php

```
<?php

$color = 'black';
include 'test2.php';
```

test2.php

```
<?php

print 'The cat is '.$color;
```

This will output:

```
The cat is black
```